# Repeat element when the entire element has been scrolled

Tags: jquery, scroll, frontend

I have a div with 100% height (of the window), and position absolute, with an image element inside of it.

When the height of the div has been scrolled, I want the div to repeat. So as soon as it leaves the window, I want to start scrolling it again. (Se attached images)

Is this possible? I assume it can be achieved somehow with jQuery?

Important: I do no want it to continue repeating after the rest of the page content has been scrolled.

[image: Element in window]

[image: Element on scroll]

Comment: what ve you tried?? we need at least the html

Comment: When you say 100% height, do you mean 100% of the window or the document?